# node async function - get the result to the outside function

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have the following async function and want to have the value data.

I tried with Promises and Async/Awaits. I always miss something. Would be happy for some help. Thanks!

Here the async function:

```js
ad.getData("ID1", function (err, res) {
  let data = 11111;
  if ((res!= null) && (res.val != null)){
    data = res.val;
  } else {
    // store data
  }
});
```

and I tried:

```js
async function getData(id){
  return await ad.getData(id, function (err, res) {
       let data = 11111;
       if ((res!= null) && (res.val != null)){
         data = res.val;
       } else {
         // store data
       }
         return data;
        })
}
        
let data = await getData("Id1");

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Can you show this in some fiddle or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an asynchronous operation, and the code is written in callback style.

```
ad.getData("ID1", function (err, res) { // the function is a callback
  let data = 11111;
  if ((res!= null) && (res.val != null)){
    data = res.val;
  } else {
    // store data
  }
});
```

In order to get the result outside the function, or in general, write asynchronous code that look like a synchronous one, we can wrap callback style code in a Promise, like this :

```
function getDataAsync() {

  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

  // callback style code is wrapped in the Promise
  ad.getData("ID1", function (err, res) {
    let data = 11111;
    if ((res!= null) && (res.val != null)){
      data = res.val;
    } else {
      // store data
    }

    resolve(data); // it means, when the Promise is resolved, it will give you the data
});
```

And you can get the output of getDataAsync like this :

```
let data = await getDataAsync("Id1"); 
// we use "await" keyword to wait for the Promise is resolve, data is the variable in the resolve
console.log(data);
```

You should use Promise instead of callback, and async/await will help you write Promise code easier.

Please take a deep look at https://scotch.io/courses/10-need-to-know-javascript-concepts/callbacks-promises-and-async. When you understand the concept, it's literally easy.

Comment: Thank you. It works! Will do the course :-)